# Formatar buffer, php

Tags: php

Não sei se a palavra certa é buffer mas como faz para deixar o código JavaScript "limpo" dessa forma:

`({"content":"<div id=\"_sub-item\">Espere, ser\u00e1 exibido ap\u00f3s o carregamento dos itens.<\/div>"`

tá vendo que ele escorou todos os " e codificou pronto pra exibir pro navegador?

Como faz isso com PHP?

Comment: `utf8_encode()` e `utf8_decode()` tentou isso?

Comment: @rray não retorna como o esperado

Comment: Isso aí é um json certo?

Comment: @rray creio que sim, tem como ter esse mesmo efeito?

Comment: Aceite alguma resposta se resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 2):

A codificação retornada no seu exemplo faz parte da serialização gerada pela função `json_encode`.

Exemplo:

```
json_encode(array(
 'conteúdo' => '<div class="alguma-coisa">Alguma coisa e acentuação para testar</div>'
));
```

Se você quer codificar alguma string com os caracteres escapados para entidades HTML, você pode utilizar a função `htmlentities`.

```
echo htmlentities('"meu nome é wallace"');
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) para ter a saida esperada:

```
<?php
$str = "<div>Espere, será exibido após o carregamento dos itens.</div>";
$json = json_encode($str);
print_r($json);
```

Saida:

```
"<div>Espere, ser\u00e1 exibido ap\u00f3s o carregamento dos itens.<\/div>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso, aparentemente, me paresse ser uma saida JSON, no PHP você converte essa saída desta forma no PHP:

```
    $saida  = array(
                'content'=>'<div id="_sub-item">
                               Espere, será exibido após 
                               o carregamento dos itens.
                              </div>'
              );
   echo json_encode($saida);
```